# ConcurrentModificationException without iterator(implicitly or explicitly). Is it really?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have read about ConcurrentModificationException. A lot of information about obtain this exception in case iteration over collection and attempt modoficate it.

It is interesting for me Could I get this exception without using iterator?

Comment: If you read the code of ArrayList, for example, you'll see that a ConcurrentModification is thrown when its writeObject() method detects the the list has changed during the serialization. So if a thread modified a list while it's being serialized, and the serializing thread sees the modification, you'll get such an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the iterators, there are not so many places in the standard list implementations where this exception is thrown. The `writeObject` method was already mentioned in the comment. Another one is when attempting to modify a `subList` that was obtained from an `ArrayList` and the `ArrayList` has been modified in the meantime:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");

// Obtain the subList
List<String> subList = list.subList(1,2);

// Modify the backing list
list.add("X");

// Try to modify the subList: Causes ConcurrentModificationException
subList.add("Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

Comment: ahahaha))) it is really truth)))

Comment: Is it  only one variant?